# Problems with rcpp install - command not found

Tags: rstudio, rcpp

On a Mac with Sierra OS and the latest versions of xcode command line tools and r/rstudio, when trying to install rcpp I get the following error. Is this a path problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
> install.packages("Rcpp", type = "source")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.12.12.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2421289 bytes (2.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
sh: mv: command not found
** libs
sh: make: command not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rcpp’
sh: rm: command not found
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/hn/zpnk2qsx19x1y974vym8wr7r0000gn/T/RtmptRz4Oe/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Are you able to open `Terminal` (Applications/Utilities/Terminal), change directory (`cd ~/Downloads`), create a temp file (`touch temp_file.txt`), and remove it (`rm temp_file.txt`)? If yes... Did you install _R_ from a different source than the official binary @ cran.r-project.org? Or, do you have a "newer" version of bash installed via a package manager? Lastly, in a bash profile, do you override your `PATH` variable without appending to it?

Comment: So, what is the output of `Sys.getenv("PATH")`?

Comment: I can do all those things. I installed R from the official binary as well.

Comment: $ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Sys.getenv("PATH")
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/:$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin"

Comment: @coatless my bash profile is empty

Comment: Something is broken in your _R.app_ install then. Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling it? Use an app cleaner like Appcleaner or appzapper